# centering text with css

Tags: css

I am inserting text into a class `<span class="span4 offset4">` using templates.
 In the css, I used  `text-align: centre;` but the text is not centering.
 It's pushed to the left side of the div.
 I can see this because I also color the background of the div when I put the text in it.
 I even tried to wrap the message in `<p>` tags but it's not doing anything.
 Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<p>{{= message }}</p>
```

html

```
<div class="row">
  <span class="span4 offset4"></span>
</div>
```

css

```
.span4.offset4
{    
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    min-height: 25px;
    text-align: centre;     
}
```

Comment: you're asking css to center a span. a span has no paddings and whatnot, centering would not help. What you want to look into is to center the span tag in the div.

Comment: @hehui but I was coloring the background of the span, so I wanted the text inside that centre. Thanks.

Comment: yeah halfway adding an answer I realised that's what you meant. Hence I deleted my answer lol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's `center`, not `centre`.  Moreover, `display: inline` elements don't work with `text-align`.  Make the span `display: block` or something.

Answer (score 2):

Give  `text-align:center` to your parent div inside row class.

Answer (score 1):

try adding these lines to css

```
//to define size of div
.row
{
width:30%;
}
```

then add these lines to .span4.offset4

```
margin:auto auto;
```